# Android Material design customizing

Tags: android, customization, material-design

A quick question please.
I just followed a tutorial where it's explained how to change the color of the toolbar and the system bar when using Material Design. 
When using the new colors inside the v21/styles.xml, they refer them as colorPrimary and colorPrimaryDark, so I have concluded 1st one is toolbar and 2nd one is system bar. I believe it's correct as if I replace one of them by another name, Android screams.
Are there more things we can customize and is there a list of these items with their name somewhere? I have been looking around, but not successfully so far
Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to take a look at this like [here](https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html). It gives you a list of all the available parameters.

If you are using AppCompat, just use the attributes without the android prefix, so

```
<item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
```

would be replaced with

```
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thy to follow in this way 
In VALUES v21

---

style.xml

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

---

value
style.xml

```
 <!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/ColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/ColorPrimaryDark</item>

</style>
```

color.xml

```
        <color name="ColorPrimary">#ffffff</color>
        <color name="ColorPrimaryDark">#d1d1d1</color>
```

In layout

### activity_main

add this

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
    android:id="@+id/actionbar"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    android:elevation="4dp">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

---

Last step is add this line in ur Activity.java

```
 // calling android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar in ActionBar
    setSupportActionBar((Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.actionbar));
```